# How can I separate numeric array's keys from the letter keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 1;
$arr['txt'] = 'something';
$arr['txt2'] = 'something2';
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 3;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);

/* output:
   1
   something
   something2
   2
   3
*/
```

I'm trying to change array's order and make this result:

```
/* expected output:
   1
   2
   3
   something
   something2
*/
```

As you see, I need to reindex all array's items and put the numeric ones in the beginning of array. Is that possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I separate numeric array's keys from the letter keys?

Simplest way is to sort the array by key, using `ksort` which modifies the array in place.  Use the `SORT_STRING` flag to get the result you seek:

```
ksort($myArr, SORT_STRING);
```

[Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f733ac0c68ac96df37f1338719f9f46dfc25cf77)

Answer (score 1):

**The Correct syntax is:**

### - Using array values

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = 1;
    $arr['txt'] = 'something';
    $arr['txt2'] = 'something2';
    $arr[] = 2;
    $arr[] = 3;

    echo '<pre>';

    usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if (is_float($a)) {
        if ( is_float($b)) {
            return $a - $b; 
        }
        else 
            return -1;
    }
    elseif (is_float($b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }
    });

    print_r($arr);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => something
    [4] => something2
)
```

### - Using array index values

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = 1;
    $arr['txt'] = 'something';
    $arr['txt2'] = 'something2';
    $arr[] = 2;
    $arr[] = 3;

    echo '<pre>';

    usort($arr, SORT_STRING);

    print_r($arr);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [txt] => something
    [txt2] => something2
)
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[html](/questions/tagged/html)